# Why my wordpress plugin settings shows up for users other than administrator?

Tags: wordpress

I have a plugin installed in my wordpress site which allows user logins as contributor. But the settings tab for this plugin appears even if user logins as contributors.
Is there a quick way to make sure the plugin settings appear only for administrators?

Answer (score 0):

In the function where you register the plugin settings page, there's an argument for capability. Setting that to a higher capability (I usually use `'manage_options'`) prevents unauthorized access. For example:

```
add_options_page( 'My Options Page', 'My Options Page', 'manage_options', 'my-options-page', 'function_to_render_page' );
```

For more information, see the WordPress codex page on adding administration pages:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Adding_Administration_Menus